# Vercel / Nextjs middleware request object is just a string

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have a nextjs / vercel middleware that looks like this:

```
import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from "next/server";

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    console.log('test----> ', req)
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

I expect this to log some info about the request,  but instead it just logs this string,

```
test---->  { sourcePage: '/src/middleware' }
```

what is going on here?

Comment: What Next.js version are you on?